# Access 2010 Query results with image next to it

Tags: image, ms-access-2010

I have a query that returns a list of items. What I would like is to be able to display this on a form with an image (green/red circle) to indicate if the item is working or not. I'm not sure this is possible but if it is I would appreciate a pointer.

Example of form:

(Green) Truck1
(Green) Truck2
(Red) Truck3
(Red) Car1
(Green) Car2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the contents of a textbox to a wingding and code the colour. In Access 2010, you can set the colour of a toggle button to a colour and if the toggle is bound to a YesNo data type the colour will change nicely.

1. Create a Continuous form based on the relevant query. I will assume that Working is a YesNo field.
2. Add a text box in a suitable position and set the control source to `="n"`
3. Set the font of the textbox to WebDings, set the colour of the font to red
4. Right-click and choose Conditional Formatting:

[image: conditional formatting]

As you can see, I have chosen `Expression Is` and entered the name of my YesNo field. I have then selected a font colour of green.

**Result**

[image: little coloured marks]

Comment: ty for the suggest, but I admit I'm still rather lost on how to accomplish this. I thought about using a list but am not sure how to set the second field in the query, that is the list's rowsource, to be of text font webding, and its color green or red based on the other fields value. Do you have any further tips?

Comment: Which version of MS Access are you using? How do you feel about the toggle button?

Comment: Access2010 I feel fine with the toggle, I just need a visual indicator of the items status next to all the items in the list. Its just I'm not sure how to start/ what to look for.

Comment: Okay, I have the webding working with a continuous form. i will add instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the step by step!